# Making a matrix "graph" from data entered through scanner

Tags: java, matrix

I need to make graph-like matrix when a user enters their paychecks for all 12 months of year. Simplegraph will print output, rounding entered paycheck to nearest 1000.

To be specific, my output needs to look like the picture below.  For example: if a user enters a value between 1501 and 2500, it would be rounded to 2000. 
I have figured out how to round the values, but I can't figure out how to place an `X` for the correct value in the appointed month.

I suppose that I need to save the values in an array. However, if I save them in an array, I can't figure out how to place them in their appropriate month.

[image: Example Graph]

Comment: What have you done already? Show us the code. The task says it all so I don't get what exactly are you missing...

Answer (score 0):

one entry per month in the array?

when looping and creating the matrix just have a method like

```
for y
    for x
        if(shouldPutX(x,y,months))
            System.out.print("X")
        else
            System.out.print(" ")

shouldPutX(x,y,months){
    int monthVal = month[x-1]
    if monthVal should be rounded to this line
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //               creating scanner with 12 spaces (12 months)
                    int[] salaryIntArray = new int[12];
                    Scanner salary = new Scanner(System.in);

   //                 counters
                    int i = 0;
                    int j = 0;

   //                 entering salary for every month in array
                    while (i<salaryIntArray.length){
                        System.out.println("Enter syour salary:");
                        salaryIntArray [i] = salary.nextInt();
                        i++;
                    }

    //                trying to round numbers, but it doesnt work with arrays, only when I'am using simple integer variables
    //                Rules to round numbers:
    //                0 - 500  round to 0
    //                501 - 1500 round to 1000
    //                1501 - 2500 round to 2000
    //                2501 - 3500 round to 3000
    //                3501 - 4500 round to 4000
    //                4501 - 5500 round to 5000
                    int roundNumberArray = ((salaryIntArray + 499) / 1000 * 1000);


     //            System.out.println(roundedNumber);
     //         System.out.println();

     //         Test print to check to see if salaries are correctly saved
                    System.out.println();
                    int month = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j<12; j++){
                        System.out.println("Salary for " + month + " month is " + salaryIntArray[i1]);
                        month ++;
                    }
```

What I need now is to how to make table/matrix